# npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, undefined, angular-resolver

Almost every command I run with "npm" and some with "ng" returns this error.

I am starting with Nativescript and angular and I am very lost here...

Any idea about where these errors could come from?

For example, trying to create a new app with angular ("ng new angular-app")

The log returns all these errors:

```
17 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.13.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@~7.3.4 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
19 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/compiler-cli@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/language-service@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
21 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @types/node@~8.9.4 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
22 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @types/jasmine@~2.8.8 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
23 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @types/jasminewd2@~2.0.3 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for codelyzer@~4.5.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for jasmine-core@~2.99.1 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
26 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for jasmine-spec-reporter@~4.2.1 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
27 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for karma@~4.0.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
28 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for karma-chrome-launcher@~2.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
29 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@~2.0.1 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
30 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for karma-jasmine@~1.1.2 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
31 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for karma-jasmine-html-reporter@^0.2.2 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
32 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for protractor@~5.4.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
33 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for ts-node@~7.0.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
34 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tslint@~5.11.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
35 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@~3.2.2 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
36 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/animations@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
37 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/common@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
38 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/compiler@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
39 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/core@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
40 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/forms@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
41 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/platform-browser@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
42 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
43 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/router@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
44 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for core-js@^2.5.4 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
45 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for rxjs@~6.3.3 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
46 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tslib@^1.9.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
47 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for zone.js@~0.8.26 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
48 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/animations@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
49 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/common@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
50 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/compiler@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
51 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/core@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
52 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/forms@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
53 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/platform-browser@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
54 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
55 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/router@~7.2.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
56 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for core-js@^2.5.4 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
57 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for rxjs@~6.3.3 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
58 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for tslib@^1.9.0 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
59 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for zone.js@~0.8.26 Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

63 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
63 verbose stack     at regFetch (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js:76:23)
63 verbose stack     at fetchPackument (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\packument.js:42:10)
63 verbose stack     at packument (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\packument.js:20:10)
63 verbose stack     at getManifest (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:22:10)
63 verbose stack     at manifest (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:13:10)
63 verbose stack     at Object.manifest (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\index.js:17:12)
63 verbose stack     at Object.Fetcher#manifest [as manifest] (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\genfun\lib\genfun.js:15:38)
63 verbose stack     at manifest (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetch.js:23:18)
63 verbose stack     at pinflight (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\manifest.js:24:12)
63 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:29:24
63 verbose stack     at Promise._execute (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:313:9)
63 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
63 verbose stack     at new Promise (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
63 verbose stack     at _inflight (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:28:25)
63 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:22:14
63 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Marta\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.10.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
```

Comment: use latest stable node and npm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to update npm:

```
npm install npm -g
```

use sudo if you are using mac or linux

Comment: The answer is your comment. I needed to use the latest stable version. I used the command "latest" that should install, indeed, the latest stable, but for some reason, it wasn't the latest stable that you can get in the npm web page.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: "npm ERR! Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined" on this command

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The solution was to reinstall Node JS.

The best way to install node is to download it from the website: https://nodejs.org

If you need a specific release you can download the version you need from the releases page: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/.